# Rackspace Cloud Servers in Europe?

Tags: cloud-hosting, virtualhost

We have setup a cloud virtual server at rackspace in the US, but we use it from Europe. I found out I am not quite happy with the response time. Of course I knew that there would be some latency. But I am not sure if it is the overseas latency (ping is 120ms) or also the minimal resources. It is the smallest machine, 256 MB, 10 GB, running a Mediawiki on Ubuntu 10.04 64 bit. The Instance lives in the rackspace ORD1 datacenter.

As soon as they have opened their new facilities in the UK we plan moving the incstance there. But we are planing more machines already. The pricing is quite attractive.

I don't really want to do some measuring and benchmarking and this stuff, so I am asking just for your opinions and it would be nice to hear what you can tell from your experience. Maybe someone who uses such small instances in the US. And what can we really expect if we upgrade to more resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are using rackspace London v-servers for some time now, but it was not possible to migrate images, which is somehow disappointing.

You cannot restore a VM from a backup of a different VM, only from the same VM, even on the same server farm. (Because of some checksum / code that must be identical and you cannot control it)

Answer (score 0):

[Rackspace Cloud is coming to the UK soon](http://www.rackspace.co.uk/cloud-hosting/public-cloud/register-interest/)

**Update**

[It went beta last week and you can now buy cloud servers in the UK.](http://www.rackspace.co.uk/cloud-hosting/)

Comment: And this was voted down because...